# Markdown: what's the correct behavior for linking inline code?

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

This seems to be working here, but not on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31930734/178082).

I was answering a question today and wanted to add a link to an inline code block.  In markdown it looked like this:

```
`Timer`
```

Then I highlighted the word "Timer" without the quotes, pressed the link button, pasted my link, posted the answer and the link was broken, it showed up like this: `[Timer][1]`.

That fails to render as a link, but does render as inline code.  I'm not a language expert by any means, and I don't think the [spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.20/) is explicit on what should happen in this case, but it seems like this should be a valid inline code span with a link in it.

In any case, if the link box is pressed, it seems like it should try to produce a valid link from the selection.

Comment: According to the CommonMark specs: ``Backtick code spans, autolinks, and raw HTML tags bind more tightly than the brackets in link text. Thus, for example, [foo`]` could not be a link text, since the second ] is part of a code span.`` So the behavior above is expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the backticks and all.

```
This is [`code`](http://www.example.com)
```

Will be rendered as

This is [`code`](http://www.example.com)

Comment: I got that, that's how I had originally fixed it, but I reverted it on SO to show that it is not working the other way.  Of course... it is working the other way on meta, so now it's obvious there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: ... I don't see a difference. If I select the text within the backticks on meta or on so, it doesn't produce a link, it just puts the links syntax inside a code block. And on both, if I select the whole thing (including backticks), it will produce a valid linked inline code block. I guess I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

The correct markdown would be:

```
[`Timer`][1]

[1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx
```

which renders as:

[`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)